# giving a .cshtml layout to aspx file in webmatrix or any other WebPages project

Tags: c#, layout, razor, webmatrix-2

I want to give my .cshtml layout to a aspx and its respective cs file which I have included in my webmatrix project which contains all files in cshtml (razor)please help me out guys I hv searched for it a lot and found notihing,plz help out...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a cshtml layout file with an aspx web forms file. You have to use a .master page instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the thing is I am new to .net and I have started with webpages with webmatrix and finding it easy compared to webforms,so I hv a CS code which I can include in my project but can't style it with respect to my other files..

Comment: You will have to adapt the code to go into a .cshtml file. If you want help with that specifically, post a question to the WebMatrix forum at http://forums.asp.net/1224.aspx/1?WebMatrix+and+ASP+NET+Web+Pages. People don't like that kind of question at StackOverflow. It will be down voted and closed in no time. The ASP.NET forums are much more lenient.

Comment: well said @MikeBrind , I too think asp.net forums is the right place to post this ,  thanks!